# Qt, conflict between 2 QRadioButton sets

Tags: c++, qt, widget, radio-button, qradiobutton

My widget app interface holds 2 sets of QRadioButtons, independant to one another. One of the sets is actually a QDialogButtonBox of QRadioButtons.

At first both sets behave intentionally, which means, clicking on 1 button of the set unchecks the previously checked button of the same set. ALSO, it's important, if you check one button then click on it again, it DOESN'T uncheck.

But for some reason, as soon as I interact with the Button Box, the other set breaks: clicking on a checked button unchecks it, resulting in no button being checked in the set.

Any idea why?

EDIT: this might help, or not, but here's how it looks like:

[image]

The first set is composed of the 2 tabs "Presets" and "Favorites".
The second set, the QDialogButtonBox, is the list of presets underneath.

Comment: Please provide some code and screenshot if possible.

Comment: I worked using QtDesigner tool, so I don't really have any code to show. Also forgot to mention, I checked that every button's Auto-exclusive property is "true".
As for a screenshot, not sure it will help as button have been highly customized with stylesheet and don't event look like radio buttons anymore, but will post a screenshot anyway.

Comment: Could you please show easiest way to reproduce this? Like: 1. Create layout add 3 radio button. 2. Create another layout add 3 radiobutton 3. ....

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to implement your widget in some other way.

One way could be a checkable tabwidget ... you can find [some help here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818387/qtabwidget-with-checkbox-in-title). It is wirtten in `Python` but I think it's pretty simple.

But I would suggest you to use a simple `QTabWidget` ... if the checkable option is not important on the top of the widget. Why is it needed ?